# How to enable/disable tab in AngularJS front end

Tags: css, angularjs, html

I have three tabs in my page. I am not able to enable/disable the tabs correctly.When I click on the tab,routing happens which takes me to the desired page but tab remains as active only.When next time I click on the tab again it becomes deactive.

Interestingly if I remove the below piece of code,I am able to make the tabs enable/disable properly.

'window.location.assign(view);'

I am new to AngularJS/CSS etc.Can anyone please help me.Need to fix it bit urgently.Thanks in advance !

Please find my below code in html page and controller.

html-

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" > 
    <li  ng-class="{ active: isSet(1) }" style="width:130px;display:inline-block">
         <a   ng-click="setTab(1,'#/Employers')" style="background-color:#0072AD" ><b style="color:white">EMPLOYERS</b></a>                    
    </li>                                   
    <li ng-class="{ active: isSet(2) }"  style="width:110px;display:inline-block">   
        <a ng-click="setTab(2,'#/Products')"  style="background-color:#0072AD"><b style="color:white">PRODUCTS</b></a>
     </li>
      <li ng-class="{ active: isSet(3) }"  style="width:180px;display:inline-block">
         <a  ng-click="setTab(3,'#/ControlReports')"   style="background-color:#0072AD"><b style="color:white">CONTROL REPORTS</b></a>                                   
      </li>
</ul>
```

Controller:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('Business.Header', [])
    .controller('HeaderCtrl', ['$scope','$location','$rootScope',
function ($scope, $location, $rootScope) {

    $scope.tab = 1;    

    $scope.isSet = function (tabNum) {

        return $scope.tab === tabNum;
    };

    $scope.setTab = function (newTab, view) {

        $scope.tab = newTab;

        window.location.assign(view);       


    };

}]);
```

CSS:

```
/* text recolor */
h1, p, a {
  color: #4DC9C9 !important;

}

/* button recolor */
.nav-pills > li.active > a, .btn-primary {
  background-color: #6C6C6C !important;  
  border-color: #6C6C6C !important;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try using ng-class without the function like i did here:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" > 
    <li  ng-class="{ active: tab === 1 }" style="width:130px;display:inline-block">
         <a ng-click="setTab(1,'#/Employers')" style="background-color:#0072AD"><b style="color:white">EMPLOYERS</b></a>                    
    </li>                                   
    <li ng-class="{ active: tab === 2 }" style="width:110px;display:inline-block">   
        <a ng-click="setTab(2,'#/Products')" style="background-color:#0072AD"><b style="color:white">PRODUCTS</b></a>
    </li>
    <li ng-class="{ active: tab === 3 }" style="width:180px;display:inline-block">
         <a ng-click="setTab(3,'#/ControlReports')" style="background-color:#0072AD"><b style="color:white">CONTROL REPORTS</b></a>                                   
    </li>
</ul>
```

if this isnt working you could try this:

```
$scope.setTab = function (newTab, view) {
    $scope.tab = newTab;
    window.location.assign(view);
    if($scope.$$phase) $scope.$apply();  // to force after assign
};
```

or

```
$scope.setTab = function (newTab, view) {
    $scope.tab = newTab;
    if($scope.$$phase) $scope.$apply();  // to force before assign
    window.location.assign(view);
};
```

Comment: I tried.But still not working.It is behaving like before-on 1st click,routing is happening and on 2nd click on the tab,colore is changing to #6C6C6C(deactivation of tab).Can you please provide me some other solution.

Comment: I tried these two approaches also.Regarding $scope.$apply(),I tried earlier.It is still not working,behaving exactly same.

Comment: is there a reason why you are using window.location.assign instead of [ng-view](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView)?

Comment: I did not know about ng-view.I just checked how to use it,but bit confused.Can you please advise.

Comment: I added <div ng-view></div>  and href="#/Employers",href="#/Products" and href="#/ControlReports" in the html page as below and commented window.location.assign(view) in controller.But now the page is becoming-unresponsive.Can someone advise please.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the name of class inside single quote - **'active'**

Like this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" > 
    <li  ng-class="{ 'active': tab == 1 }" style="width:130px;display:inline-block">
         <a   ng-click="setTab(1,'#/Employers')" style="background-color:#0072AD" ><b style="color:white">EMPLOYERS</b></a>                    
    </li>                                   
    <li ng-class="{ 'active': tab == 2 }"  style="width:110px;display:inline-block">   
        <a ng-click="setTab(2,'#/Products')"  style="background-color:#0072AD"><b style="color:white">PRODUCTS</b></a>
     </li>
      <li ng-class="{ 'active': tab == 3 }"  style="width:180px;display:inline-block">
         <a  ng-click="setTab(3,'#/ControlReports')"   style="background-color:#0072AD"><b style="color:white">CONTROL REPORTS</b></a>                                   
      </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Tried...It is behaving like before-on 1st click,routing is happening and on 2nd click on the tab only,colore is changing to #6C6C6C(deactivation of tab)

Comment: I create this plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/mRVj1vrZsuZZcUd0P1aO?p=preview following your code, it works fine. Can you edit and show us your problem clearly?

Comment: Thanks for your help.The code you mentioned in the plunker works fine for me too.But it does not work when page gets redirected to different .html files(when page reload happens).I just added app.js file in the plunker where routing is happening to route to Employer.html,Products.html and ControlReports.html.I think this is where the issue is (in page reload/redirecting because if I comment window.location.assign(view) ,it works just like your code ).Kindly check if you are able to view it(as I am using plunker for the first time and not sure whether I am able to save my code).

Comment: I can't see your modification, but i understand your problem maybe.
You can try to use $rootScope instead $scope for *tab* variable.
When you change and load new route, angular change $scope too

Comment: Please see my last mentioned modification - https://plnkr.co/edit/HiUhO8gES5iW46mcSPtA?p=preview.I have added here app.js file which does the routing.Also as per your advice,I changed $scope to $rootScope for tab variable,but it did not work.

Comment: Any advice from anyone please..need to fix it real quick...Thanks !

Comment: I just fixed the issue.it was mainly twich hitting of the header controller.so once tab is activated/deactivated ,put a condition using a variable true and false)so that flow does not hit the controller again.Thanks!